# Parallel update issue in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, concurrency

We have one field which gets updated on user action, admin action, and in cron at the same time then what should we do in order to handle this kind of scenario in MongoDB.

e.g There is a "balance" field in the user's collection when the cron is running user's balance is decreased, now at the same time if the user is recharging and admin is refunding then the balance is not getting updated.

So please suggest any solution for this problem.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Explain what you are doing now. Document updates are atomic, so if you're using update operations everything should be ok. If you're using read-update-write, then there are multiple ways this can be solved.

Comment: @BurakSerdar we are first fetching user's balance then add in balance finally save in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, use update operations. They are atomic at the document level, so this should not be a problem.

If you are using a recent version of mongodb, you can use transactions for read-update-writes.

If you cannot do any of these, you can emulate an optimistic locking scheme using versioning to prevent unintended overwrites. There are several ways this can be done, but it generally goes like this:

- Read the document. Document has a version field (which can be an integer, or a unique ObjectId. Don't use timestamp)
- Make modifications in memory and update the version (increment the integer, or generate a new ObjectId)
- Update the document with query containing (version: oldVersion)

This will fail if someone updated the document after you read it but before you updated it. If it fails, retry.

Comment: We've implemented mongodb transaction in both places where balance is getting updated. Now in first code transaction is executed successfully but in other place where balance is also being updated at the same time, we get write conflict error in transaction. So what can we do to solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to keep a process in a queue at the document level instead of retrying the transaction?

Comment: What do you mean by "queue"? The transaction fails because it detects a change during the transaction. The only reasonable thing you can do is to retry it.